# Why do ksh88 and ksh93 allow unclosed backticks?

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I have a question.

I don't get it why when I type:

```
echo "`date -d 20121231 +"%B
```

It executes without errors:

```
December
```

Why it executes successfully when the opening

> **`**

is not closed at the end?
It works on both Korn Shell 88 and 93.

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: what shell? zsh doesn't like it :)

Comment: This does not execute correctly with `bash` (three different versions), bash-as-sh or `csh` for me.

Comment: Absolutely. It works on Korn Shell 88 nad 93.

Comment: It would seem that ksh is auto-closing the backtick when the word/line ends for some reason. `echo "\`d"ate` also works but `echo \`"d"ate` waits for a closing backtick.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `echo` -- it would behave the same way with any other command; nor does it relate to any UNIX shell other than (official, written-by-David-Korn) implementations of ksh. Editing the title appropriately.

Comment: Just to add to the list, this doesn't work in `pdksh`.

Comment: That said -- we're now in the realm of "why did [language implementor] make [decision]?", and those questions tend to get closed around here because only that person can give a definitive answer; otherwise, we have people debating their personal guesses -- lots of heat, very little light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was (if intentional) a decision made by David Korn.

There is no requirement for this behavior made by external forces -- no backwards compatibility requirement; no standards compliance reason (for that matter, POSIX sh was not yet standardized when ksh88 came out).

The only person who can give a definitive answer for the rationale -- if any -- behind unspecified behavior (behavior neither implementing not breaking any documented semantics) is the author of these shells.

Comment: This has all the hallmarks of a bug in the `ksh` implementation; I cannot find any reference to this behaviour in the man page, and other example such as `echo "x` and `echo \`ls` behave as one should expect. Other `ksh` version `pdksh` & `mksh` also don't exhibit this behaviour).

Comment: Bug? Undocumented behavior? Again, only one person can say, and chances are he's not here. That said, you're right that a bug is likely, and I've amended my wording appropriately.

Comment: It's not impossible this is intentional, but it seems to me that a bug is *far* more likely than that this strange & inconsistent behaviour is intentional, the parsing in `sh_lex` is a 1200 function with up to 8 levels of nesting. It's bound to have some bugs... You edited the title of the question by the way, and it's not as simpel as "unclosed backticks"; the `"` starts before the backtick, and is closed *before the end of the command*... This is wrong in any case, and this is *probably*  where `sh_lex()` gets confused, somehow...